# Error while Installing Rails 3.2.3 (While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError))

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently installed ruby 1.9.3 and rubygems 1.8.24. Both installed perfectly (src: http://railsapps.github.com/installing-rails.html). However, when I proceeded to install rails 3.2.3 (the latest stable version), I got following errors:

$ gem install rails

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: railties requires thor (~> 0.14.6), rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2), rdoc (~> 3.4); actionmailer requires mail (~> 2.4.4); activerecord requires tzinfo (~> 0.3.29); sprockets requires hike (~> 1.2), tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1)

Googling for the possible solution, I tried:

$ gem install rails --include-dependencies

and got following error:

INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed

INFO:  use --ignore-dependencies to install only the gems you list

Fetching: i18n-0.6.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: multi_json-1.3.4.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/activesupport-3.2.3.gem)

can anyone help me with the command line solution to be used for installing the aforementioned dependencies. Any additional explanation will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this first: **gem update --system** do you run it with administrator rights?

Comment: Hey guys, nevermind. I guess there was some problem with network connection. I retried the command **gem install rails --include-dependencies** and it installed like a butter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nevermind. I guess there was some problem with network connection. I retried the command gem install rails --include-dependencies and it installed like a butter.